# Efficiently handling many hotspots on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Is there a good way to handle a large number of hotspots on a PictureBox in a WinForm?  We're talking potentially hundreds.  I know a couple of ways I could do this, but none of them seem to be particularly expedient.  I know I can use a MouseMove event and compare the coordinates to see if the mouse is within a given rectangle, but this will likely become inefficient with more than just a few hotspots to check.  I could alternatively generate lots of invisible Panels to capture the mouse events, but I'm not sure if this would ultimately be any more efficient than storing and checking against hundreds of Rectangles.  I think a k-d-tree of some sort might work, but that may be seriously over-engineering this problem.  I'm wondering if there's some sort of already-existing (and optimized) system in WinForms for dealing with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, checking whether a point is in a rectangle is pretty quick - and the first thing I'd do is create a control and define 1000 hotspots (or what you might feel the maximum is), and then see what the performance is like.

If it *is* too slow, you might want to look at implementing a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  Essentially this will divide your area in to larger areas, which then have sub-areas, which then can have sub, areas, etc.

Depending on where your mouse is, you're only going to have to check a *subset* of the areas because you know that if the mouse is in one of the larger areas, you don't have to check the rest.

Beware, of course, of rectangles that intersect larger areas, so you might have to end up checking more of the larger areas than you need.  But the QuadTree idea should get you started and will give you a performance boost.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about a quadtree (just a more specific k-d-tree), I just thought it'd be a lot of work to set one up unless I was lucky enough that one already existed in the standard libraries.  If it were an on-click thing, I doubt it'd be a problem, but we're talking about checking 1000 rectangles _every frame_ whenever the mouse is moving, so I thought that might be a bad plan.  (Haven't start coding any of this because I was trying to decide which was the best approach to this problem.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman In these scenarios, I usually write a test-harness application.  SO in this case, rather than code the app, I would write a quick Windows form app with a picture box of the desired size and 1000 randomly created rectangles that "paint" themselves on collision.  This should give you an idea of what the performance is like.  You *might* find out it is a non-issue.  And also, you probably know this, but make sure you track the mouse position and are sure it *has* changed before doing your intersections.

Comment: Well, I have it running now just going through a list of rectangles and checking them all (it currently just updates a ToolTip), and it seems to run okay, but I won't be able to tell until the rest of the project is further along if the performance is acceptable.  My gut tells me that a linear-time search on a per-frame operation is a Bad Thing, but I'm not sure if this is going to break the bank.  I may attempt a quad-tree later, but it's a good deal more complicated, and the returns might be negligible...